# Rails: Change my development database from sqlite to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I've got a Rails app which currently uses sqlite in development and postgresql in production on Heroku. However, I'm trying to change this so that I use postgresql in development.

My Gemfile currently looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'chart-js-rails'
gem 'gon'
gem 'lodash-rails'

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '3.1.0'
end
```

So in the development group I've replaced the `'sqlite3' gem` with the `'pg' gem`.

I've modified the database.yml to look something like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: abc_development
  username: abc
  password: password1

test:
  <<: *default
  database: abc_test
  username: abc
  password: password1

production:
  <<: *default
  database: abc_production
  username: abc
  password: password1
```

I've executed `bundle install --without production` however, when I try `bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate` I receive the following error:

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I see Rails is right: you specified the `pg` gem only in group `production`, but you said you want to use it also in development.

So just move it from the `production` group to the beginning of your `Gemfile`

Comment: My OP showed what my Gemfile originally looked like, however, in the development group I've replaced the 'sqlite3' gem with the 'pg' gem. I've updated the OP to the actually Gemfile that I've tried.

Comment: Ok, are you sure you are running the rake db:migrate in the right environment? However, I would suggest you to move the gem pg file outside of the group, to be sure yhat the gem is laded in all environments

Comment: Hmm, okay so moving it outside of the group worked. Thanks.